# TCPDF Pyidoungsu(unicode) font order error

Tags: php, unicode, tcpdf

I used this way to add font and print pdf but font order is not corrected.
In pdf.php

```html
require_once('tcpdf_include.php');

$pdf = new TCPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);

$pdf->setPrintHeader(false);
$pdf->setPrintFooter(false);

$pdf->AddPage('P', 'A7');
$fontname = TCPDF_FONTS::addTTFfont('../fonts/Pyidaungsu-2.5.1_Regular.ttf', 'TrueTypeUnicode', '', 32);
$pdf->SetFont($fontname, '', 14, true);
```

I write correct font order but

```
$block1 = <<<EOF

<table style="font-size:9px; text-align:center">

    <tr>
        
        <td style="width:160px;">
    
            <div>
            
                Date: $saledate

                
                <p style="font-size:10px">Aung Kyaw Oo(တောင်းဖျာနှီးကုန်)</p>
                
                

            </div>

        </td>

    </tr>


</table>

EOF;

$pdf->writeHTML($block1, false, false, false, false, '');
```

I used database in utf_8general_ci

Font order error in Myanmar font (Pyidoungsu unicode font) in pdf `တောင်းဖျာနှီးကုန်` as `"တ‌ောင်းဖျာနှီးကုန်"`

Comment: Please include your code as text, not as images

Comment: @WBM, sorry this is my first time. I edited my question

Answer (score 0):

We solved this problem by using Zawgyi Font.

Since TCPDF have rendering problem in Myanmar Unicode Font but it's ok in Zawgyi Font. So we use zawgyi font and convert our original Unicode content into Zawgyi using Rabbit Converter.

You can see full source code int this is our public repo.
https://github.com/aungkoman/pdf_generate/

```php
require("Rabbit.php");
function uni2zg($str){
    return Rabbit::uni2zg($str);
}

$pdf->SetFont($font_family = 'zawgyi', $variant = '', $fontsize = 11);
$pdf->Text(0, 0, uni2zg("သီဟိုဠ်မှ ဉာဏ်ကြီးရှင်သည် အာယုဝဍ္ဎနဆေးညွှန်းစာကို ဇလွန်ဈေးဘေး ဗာဒံပင်ထက် အဓိဋ္ဌာန်လျက် ဂဃနဏဖတ်ခဲ့သည်။"));
```